# Como inserir double quote literal sem que a string " se torne \"?

Tags: c#, lucene

Trabalho com um buscador chamado [Lucene.net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) que nada mais é que um motor de busca.

Preciso inserir as seguinte frases dentro do indexador separadas por `;`:

> "bedside lamp";"lampshade";"table lamp"

É necessário ter as aspas duplas(`"`) pois ele entende que é uma frase, então só irá recuperar algo se for escrita a frase por completo, como diz [nesse manual](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Terms):

> A query is broken up into terms and operators. There are two types of terms: Single Terms and Phrases.
>
> A Single Term is a single word such as "test" or "hello".
>
> A Phrase is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as "hello dolly".

Porém quando eu utilizo [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) ele retorna uma string assim:

`\"bedside lamp\";\"lampshade\";\"table lamp\"`

Segue o exemplo:

```
PhraseIndex translation = new PhraseIndex()//Objeto que eu vou armazenar no buscador
        {
            PT_BR = "abajur;luminária",
            EN_US = "bedside lamp;lampshade;table lamp",
            ES = "pantalla;lámpara;claraboya"
        };
translation.InsertOnLucene();//Método que armazena(o modo como armazena nao afeta a pergunta, então é desnecessário)
List<String> phrases = translation.EN_US.Split(';').ToList(); //Separo todas as frases da variável EN_US dentro de uma lista
foreach(string p in translation.EN_US)
{
    translation.EN_US = translation.EN_US +p.PadLeft(p.Length+1,'"').PadRight(p.Length+1,'"') + ";"; //Aqui eu insiro uma aspas dupla no inicio e no fim de cada frase e insiro novamente dentro de EN_US separadas por ;
}

Console.WriteLine(translation.EN_US); //\"bedside lamp\";\"lampshade\";\"table lamp\" o c# insere automaticamente o " para \" sendo assim quando eu passar essa string no Lucene, ele não irá encontrar nada que tenha \"
```

O problema é que o Lucene entende o `\"` como sendo `\"` e não `"` tanto que no mesmo documento citado acima, na sessão **Escaping Special Characters** ele cita que deve-se usar o `\` para criar essas excessões.

A questão é: Eu consigo mandar para o buscador uma string

`"bedside lamp";"lampshade";"table lamp"`

ao invés de

`\"bedside lamp\";\"lampshade\";\"table lamp\"`

Pois se eu busco `lamp` ele me retorna `bedside lamp` pois não está buscando frases e sim termos.

Comment: Uma solução bem tosca é usar replace.  minhaVar.Replace("\\", string.Empty)

Comment: Automaticamente o  c# converte de volta e insere o `\"`...

Comment: Por favor, monte um [mcve].

Comment: O que você está vendo no debugger é uma representação da aspona; ela está lá, só que o debugger coloca `\"` para escapar e diferenciar a aspona das aspas de string C#.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Nossa, sério ? não acredito rsrs... vou ver se é isso mesmo(quando a gente acha que sabe de algo... aparece uma dessas)

Comment: @MarceloUchimura você tem razão ! o problema é que eu estava vendo do debugger. Acredito que o meu problema sobre o lucene esteja em outro ponto. De qualquer forma você respondeu a duvida, quer criar uma resposta? ou posso fechar a pergunta(prefiro que você crie pois pode ser a duvida de outra pessoa).

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não existe nenhum problema.

Comment: @LINQ com certeza vocÊ entende mais que eu da plataforma, mas não acha importante? acho que vai ter mais pessoas com problema parecido alguma hora... por pura desinformação pois se trata da plataforma Visual Studio... não concordo em fecha-la mas tudo bem, se for a regra ok.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Eu acho que não é importante não, por isso o voto. De qualquer forma, não há regra sobre isso, é só meu voto. Se a comunidade concordar a pergunta será fechada, caso contrário ela fica aberta 

Comment: Tudo bem @LINQ ^^ pensei que era alguma regra, vlw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O depurador do Visual Studio, quando encontra uma aspa dentro de uma string, ele a escapa porque é a representação usual de aspas dentro de strings,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que na verdade ela existe dentro da string como uma aspa sem a barra invertida de escape,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]